# Spring @value does not set property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have class that one of it's parameters i want to set from properties file:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
(..)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ConvertNonStandardOfferRequestDtoWrapper {
    private ConvertNonStandardOfferRequestDto convertNonStandardOfferRequestDto;

    @Value("true")
    private boolean documentPrintoutsRequired;

    public ConvertNonStandardOfferRequestDtoWrapper(ConvertNonStandardOfferRequestDto convertNonStandardOfferRequestDto) {
        this.convertNonStandardOfferRequestDto = convertNonStandardOfferRequestDto;
    }
}
```

What i see inside constructor is that `documentPrintoutsRequired` is `false` instead of `true`. I see that when debuging and setting breakpoint inside constructor. And i have a pom file for this module:

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>    
    <parent>
        <groupId>x</groupId>
        <artifactId>policy</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>policy-api</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>x</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        (...)
    </build>    
</project>
```

I am wonderning why `@value` does not work correctly ?

Comment: Ofcourse it is `false` in the constructor. The `@Value` will be resolved after the object has been constructed, hence after the constructor.

Comment: After object returns from my constructor it still has this field setup to `false`

Comment: It will be set after spring processed it. Also HOW are you constructing the objet. I you are constructing it yourself, instead of defining it as a bean in Spring nothing will happen. `@Value` will only work for Spring managed beans.

Comment: ok.. thanks - i create it using `new` keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd advise you use constructor inyection for all attributes, this way you'll see the injected @Value during construction time.

Besides **the class must be a Spring bean**, so add @Component annotation:

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ConvertNonStandardOfferRequestDtoWrapper {
    private ConvertNonStandardOfferRequestDto convertNonStandardOfferRequestDto;

    private boolean documentPrintoutsRequired;

    public ConvertNonStandardOfferRequestDtoWrapper(ConvertNonStandardOfferRequestDto convertNonStandardOfferRequestDto, 
                                                    @Value("${yourproperty}") boolean documentPrintoutsRequired) {
        this.convertNonStandardOfferRequestDto = convertNonStandardOfferRequestDto;
        this.documentPrintoutsRequired = documentPrintoutsRequired;
    }
}
```

Comment: One time I want to use value from property, other time not - this is the cause of using this constructor. Please tell me why i don't see accurate value in the field?

Comment: If you have @Value in the attribute you won't see the injected value during constructor execution. This is so because Spring injects fields AFTER the constructor has finished executing.

Comment: After object returns from my constructor it still has this field setup to `false`

Comment: What's the content of your `@Value(XXXX)`? It should follow this format `@Value("${name.of.a.property.from.application.yml}")`, e.g: in application.yml: `my-prop: "myvalue"` -> `@Value("${my-prop}")`

Comment: i tried simple case like value from start `true` and even this does not work.

Comment: Well in that case it should work, this may sound obvious, but... is your ConvertNonStandardOfferRequestDtoWrapper class a Spring bean? Does it have @Component or has it been registered as a <bean>?

Comment: No - i create it by `new` keyword for example.

Comment: Then that's the reason: Spring has nothing to do with classes constructed directly using their constructors. Add `@Component` annotation to your class and you' see that it now injects the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the value from properties file, such as 
username = Tom.

use `@Value` in Java, you can set a default value like this:

```
@Value("${username:Jack}")
```

If the username does not exist in properties file, it will be "Jack".

Comment: @yami Did you set the <context : property-placeholder> label in the springmvc.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```java
@Value("${yourPropInPropertiesFile}")
private boolean documentPrintoutsRequired;
```

Comment: Could you post tour properties file please ?